# Pause command parameters in CMD/BATCH?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pause

Does the Pause command in CMD have parameters? I know that adding `>nul` to it makes it not give off the message but has the same effect, also it is not a parameter and does the same/similar thing for other commands. The documentation (found by typing `pause /?`) doesn't show any parameters, suggesting that there are no other ones. Despite this, are there any?

Comment: there are no parameters with `pause`  - `>nul` is no parameter but a redirection (has nothing to do with the command itself)

Comment: Anything else? well `pause <nul` does just shows the text, but doesn't wait.

Comment: Most commands in batch you can add `/?` to view any available switches/parameters.

Comment: To have more options use `timeout /?` or `choice /?`

Comment: I am asking what else can be done with the Pause command, not alternatives.

Comment: Why are you expecting it to do anything beyond suspending the processing of a batch file and displaying the message "Press any key to continue..."?

Comment: One alternative use to `pause` command is to consume characters. It reads one character from its input stream each time it is executed. Try with `echo test | (>nul pause & more)` and `echo test | (>nul (pause&pause) & more)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pause` command doesn't have any arguments, options or switches, except `/?`.

Type `pause /?` into a command prompt window and read the help text:

> ```cmd
> Suspends processing of a batch program and displays the message
>     Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

---

Any `> nul` or `< nul` part prepended or appended to `pause` or to any other command is called [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

- `nul` is the so-called Null device that can be used to suppress display messages or to retrieve empty input;
- the `>` operator redirects the console standard output of a command to somewhere; so `> nul` suppresses the display text (like `Press any key to continue . . .`);
- the `<` operator redirects the console standard input of a command to somewhere; so `< nul` replaces the keyboard input by nothing, so the command does not wait for user input;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set` command instead if you want to have a pause.
This will ask for an input , but will get the same effect as of Pause with a custom message.

```
Set /p P= 'Custom message'
```

This will set the entered string in P and can be obtained using %p%

Regards,

Comment: I am asking what else can be done with the Pause command, not alternatives. But thanks for your answer anyways!

Comment: The correct syntax is: `set /P VAR="Custom message"`; the apostrophies are just normal characters to `cmd` and are output literally; the entered text becomes assigned to variable `VAR` then; and do not put spaces around the `=`...

Comment: @Squashman: you don't need a variable name, if you just want to display a text. Prasoon: other than `pause`, you can't just press "any key", but have to press ENTER

Comment: @Stephan, I was correcting his answer.  His comment says he is assigning to the variable P, but it is not.